# Exception in staging but works in local : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, html

I'm working on a asp.net core 6.0 project.

I try to read a html file like this and this path is working fine in local.

Inside CheckoutConfirmCommand.cs:

```
var start = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"../Application/Cart/Commands/CheckoutConfirm/HtmlFiles/Start.html");
```

But in staging environment I got error like this:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Application/Cart/Commands/CheckoutConfirm/HtmlFiles/Start.html'.

Why does this error happen in staging? What is the mistake?

Relative path of Start.Html: `src/Application/Cart/Commands/CheckoutConfirm/HtmlFiles/Start.html`

Relative path of CheckoutConfirmCommand.cs: `src/Application/Cart/Commands/CheckoutConfirm/CheckoutConfirmCommand.cs`

Comment: why starting with `../Application`? Without knowing how you actually setup your app, I'd say you'd rather go with `Application/Cart` or directly `Cart`

Comment: I tried with strating with`Application/Cart`, but I got this error `Could not find a part of the path /src/WebApi/Application/Cart/Commands/CheckoutConfirm/HtmlFiles/Start.html`.
WebApi, Application are two different folder inside src.